# Loading object as Geometry instead of BufferGeometry in threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, stl-format

I'm trying to load an `.stl` file into three.js. Everything works fine and I get the model as BufferGeometry using this code:

```
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event )
    {

        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0x888888,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });

        var bufferGeometry = event.content;
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add( mesh );
    });
    loader.load( 'model.stl' );
```

To make it easier to further manipulate the model I would like to have the geometry as regular `THREE.Geometry` instead of `THREE.BufferGeometry`. Is it possible to either load the `.stl` in a way so I receive it as a `THREE.Geometry` or is it possible to convert from `THREE.BufferGeometry` to `THREE.Geometry`? Or is this possible using a `.obj` file or sth else?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**This answer only applies to versions of three.js prior to r.125.**

`STLLoader` now returns a `BufferGeometry` object.

You can convert that to a `THREE.Geometry` like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( bufferGeometry );
```

three.js r.124